# How can I discover tests in specific locations using folder wildcards?

Tags: python, django

I have my tests directory set up as such -

```
tests/
    unit/
        views.py
    integration/
        services.py
```

Is it possible to specify that I want to run either all unit or integration tests without hard coding the application name? I was hpping I could do something like `--pattern='**/tests/unit/*.py'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from app import test_settings
from django.core.management import call_command
import django
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.test_settings')
django.setup()

# We only suppose 'unit' and 'integration' tests
test_type = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else 'unit'
for app_name in test_settings.CUSTOM_APPS:
    try:
        module = '{}.tests.{}'.format(app_name, test_type)
        __import__(module)
        print('Module \'{}\' exists. Running {} tests...'
              .format(module, test_type))
        call_command('test', module, verbosity=2, failfast=True, pattern='*.py')
    except ImportError:
        print('Module \'{}\' doesn\'t exist. Checking next...'.format(module))
```

Answer (score 3):

with the glob module

```
import glob
print glob.glob("tests/unit/*.py")
```

then you could manually pass the files from there .... but Im not sure this is actually what you are looking for ...

something like this

**run_tests.py**

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*/tests/unit/*.py")
os.system("admin.py runtests "+" ".join(files))
```

Comment: Basically, I'm looking to use django's `manage.py test` command to specify whether I want to run unit tests or integration tests based on the directory structure I showed above. Note that I have applications within my project, which is why I'd like to specify a folder level wildcard and not a file level wildcard that the `--filter` switch uses.

Comment: Much easier than the answer I posted! Great idea.